# Array becomes undefined whenever I try and access an element

Tags: reactjs, express

### Some Background

I am currently using React's context API to pass data collected from my API (Nodejs, Express, MongoDB) through components. There is an array named **boards**, in which I store the ID of various 'boards' the user is subscribed to, which will be later used to make GET or fetch requests to retrieve information about them.

When I first read the value in React:

```
       fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/users/login', options)
.then(res => res.json())
.then( res => {
  if(res.status !== 200) { setMessage(res.message) } 
  else {
    setMessage(""); 
    setLogged(true); 
    setuserID(res.userID); 
    setToken(res.token); 
    setBoards(res.boards); } //Retrieve boards here
    console.log(res);
 });
```

I later access the value of **boards** in a different component, where I need to use its elements to generate URLs for GET requests.

### The Problem

When I log the value of boards:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(boards);  
  });
```

[The value of the array in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRp2g.png)

Though, when I try access it basically:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(boards[0]);  
  });
```

I get:

> TypeError: boards is undefined

Any help on identifying the problem here would be appreciated.

Comment: try update the code like this useEffect(() => {
    console.log(boards[0]);  
  }, [boards]); and check whether boards response first element are you getting it

Comment: Hey nerrma, can You show the place where you define boards state?

Comment: seems like you trying to get boards before it has initialised. Try to add a second parameter to `useEffect(() => {...}, [boards])`

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Thanks for the quick response! I tried adding a second parameter i.e `useEffect(()=>{...}, [boards]);` though still got the same TypeError.

Comment: add an if condition in the above code and try ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I got it working by using the exact code `useEffect(() => { if(boards) console.log(boards[0]);}, [boards]);` thank you for the active response.

Comment: I have posted the answer kindly accept and vote if it helped you

Comment: Also added the issue when you were not passing the array deps as second argument of useEffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the api needs to resolve you need to have check, you can try with below code

```
useEffect(() => { if(boards) console.log(boards[0]);}, [boards]);
```

Note:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(boards);  
  });
```

this will call every time, every render thats the reason even though the api takes time you were able to see.

You can read more about second argument of useEffect [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)